# Using NSMediaQueries and Sandboxing

Tags: macos, cocoa, sandbox, nsurl

I'm using NSMediaQueries to detect new screenshots that have been taken. But to push my App to the Store I need it to be sandboxed.

Unfortunately, the sandbox broke my NSMediaQueries since I can't access the returned URLs.

I know Cloud App is sandboxed and is able to grab the latest screenshots.

Does anyone have a clew how to fix this ?

Thanks.

Extracts of the code :

```
query = [[NSMetadataQuery alloc] init];

[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(queryUpdated:) name:NSMetadataQueryDidStartGatheringNotification object:query];
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(queryUpdated:) name:NSMetadataQueryDidUpdateNotification object:query];
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(queryUpdated:) name:NSMetadataQueryDidFinishGatheringNotification object:query];

[query setDelegate:self];
[query setPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"kMDItemIsScreenCapture = 1"]];
[query startQuery];
```

---

```
numberOfScreenshots = [query resultCount];
[self uploadToAmazonS3:[[[query results]objectAtIndex:([query resultCount]-1)]valueForAttribute:NSMetadataItemURLKey]];
```

Comment: What is it that you're accessing? Are the returned URLs on the pasteboard? Also, when sandboxing you have to enable entitlements for what you want your app to do. You should read the [App Sandbox Design Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Security/Conceptual/AppSandboxDesignGuide/AboutAppSandbox/AboutAppSandbox.html) to ensure you have implemented Sandboxing correctly.

Comment: I read it. These are screenshot images ?
Yeah they do return URLs (which in non-sandboxed mode point to the desktop)

Comment: Where are you accessing the URLs from?  Can you post some code?

Comment: Updated with extracts of code. Curious to see what I did wrong

Comment: What do you see when you NSLog [query results]?  If you aren't getting an array of `NSMetadataItem`s back something is broken.  I would start setting a ton of NSLogs in the code to see where its failing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a discussion with Apple. It turns out that if you don't have access to the folder, the URL will just be `nil`.